# Can a stressful Wish's Strength reduction be cured early by a Greater Restoration spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, ability-scores, wish

Casting a stressful [Wish](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish) has dire consequences, including a Strength reduction:

> The stress of casting this spell to produce any effect other than duplicating another spell weakens you. [...] In addition, your Strength drops to 3, if it isn't 3 or lower already, for 2d4 days. For each of those days that you spend resting and doing nothing more than light activity, your remaining recovery time decreases by 2 days.

The [Greater Restoration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/greater-restoration) spell can normally be used to cure an ability score reduction :

> You can [...] end [...] any reduction to one of the target's ability scores

Is the Greater Restoration spell strong enough to undo a Stressful Wish's Strength reduction early ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## By RAW, yes, as the rules for *Wish* don't say anything about magic not being able to end the reduction

You've already quoted in your question the relevant portion of *Greater Restoration*, which says that it can end any reduction in Ability Scores. In 5e, Specific beats General, and there are no hidden rules. Because *Wish* doesn't say anything about the Strength decrease that you haven't already mentioned, the more specific rules are those of *Greater Restoration.*

Do note, however, that *Greater Restoration* does nothing about the other effects of *Wish*'s stress.

Answer (score 15):

### A *Greater Restoration* can cure the ability score reduction caused by a stressful *Wish*.

*[Wish](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish)* (PHB 288):

> The stress of casting this spell to produce any effect other than
>   duplicating another spell weakens you. After enduring that stress,
>   each time you cast a spell until you finish a long rest, you take 1d10
>   necrotic damage per level of that spell. This damage can’t be reduced
>   or prevented in any way. In addition, your Strength drops to 3, if it
>   isn’t 3 or lower already, for 2d4 days. For each of those days that
>   you spend resting and doing nothing more than light activity, your
>   remaining recovery time decreases by 2 days. Finally, there is a 33
>   percent chance that you are unable to cast wish ever again if you
>   suffer this stress.

Note that the necrotic damage caused by this stressful Wish can't be reduced by any means, but the ability score reduction has no such text.

*[Greater Restoration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/greater-restoration)* (PHB 246):

> - Any reduction to one of the target’s ability scores

Can restore any ability score reduction including that of a (stressful) *Wish*.